# openEMR configuration for MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql

1. MySQL workbench server status: Server running and connection successful.
2. OpenEMR: asks to move the openemr folder to root directory of webserver.
   https://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/OpenEMR_5.0.1_Windows_Installation.
3. Steps taken: Moved the folder to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0, and all subdirectories under the above folder, but openEMR is not launching, from any of the options tried.

Question: Where should I put the openemr folder?

Answer (score 0):

The root directory of the webserver, is the root directory from *where files are served*. It doesn't mean `C:\`.

The `MySQL Server 8.0` should never be under where the web server serves files. Recommend putting this directory back on its original location.

Comment: 1. The original location of openemr is a .zip file that was downloaded from the internet, and extracted. 2. I have used mysql-installer-web-community to install mysql DBMS. 3. No modification to the mysql installation has been done.

Comment: The download location is irrelevant. What webserver are you running? Where is the web server root (also called the document root)?

Comment: MYSQL 8.0.  Current mysql8 directories are: 1. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0. 2. C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

Comment: Don't move the MySQL files/directories. EVER. Just don't. Reread the install instructions carefully.

Comment: 1.OK I am not moving any files/folders/directories as installed by mysqlinstaller.exe. 2. But as noted above openemr Wiki page asks to put the openemr folder into the WEBSERVER ROOT directory. 3. As far as I recall I ran into similar problem 3-4 years ago, but somehow was successful in running openEMR using mysql. Can't recall the technicalities of why I succeeded before.

Answer (score 0):

installing openemr->downloading package, step 2 states should move the openemr folder to c:\xampp\htdocs

https://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/OpenEMR_5.0.2_Windows_Installation

also a recent bug fix for patch 2 not released yet which will help get openemr and mysql8 up and running for you, https://github.com/openemr/openemr/commit/fba02face60c47b06ed4de6e7a84d6c97ca0e2b3